# How to properly extend Yoast's WPSEO_Twitter class in a theme for WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, class, extend, yoast

**Task:**
To allow CMS users to change the image used when sharing a post to Twitter. Yoast uses the Featured Image when creating the Twitter Card.

**The approach:**
Add a custom meta field to posts. Extend the WPSEO_Twitter class and or just the private function output_metatag(). If the custom meta field is not empty, use the custom field value instead of the default.

**Code:**

```
if (class_exists('WPSEO_Twitter')) :
    remove_action( 'wpseo_head', array( 'WPSEO_Twitter', 'get_instance' ), 40 );
    add_action( 'wpseo_head', array( 'EXAMPLE_WPSEO_Twitter', 'get_instance' ), 40 );

    class EXAMPLE_WPSEO_Twitter extends WPSEO_Twitter {
       // etc
     }
endif;
```

**Issues:**
The remove_action isn't working and the twitter meta code is being duplicated. The plugin's class and my extended class are both being executed.

**Links:** https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/blob/trunk/frontend/class-twitter.php

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier to add a filter to `wpseo_twitter_image` that changes the image to what you desire.

Something along the lines of

```
add_filter("wpseo_twitter_image", function($img) {
    if($myimg = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "custom-twitter-image", true)) {
        return $myimg;
    }
    return $img;
});
```

should probably work for you, if I understood you correctly.